# How can i make my text bold with custom font in SwiftUI Text?

Tags: text, swiftui, custom-font

How can i make my text bold with custom font in SwiftUI Text:

```
Text("Any text").font(.custom("PFDinTextCompPro-Regular", size: 10))
```

`.fontWeight(.heavy)` and `.custom("PFDinTextCompPro-Regular", size: 10).bold()` not working!

But this works on Android with the same .ttf file!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you have added the custom font in your .plist file. Similarly you should have the "PDFinTextCompPro-heavy/bold" ttf in the .plist . If you haven't, check this link out.

[Link to Custom font config](https://www.simpleswiftguide.com/how-to-use-custom-fonts-in-swift-ios-app-using-swiftui/#:%7E:text=Click%20on%20Info.,icon%20in%20the%20first%20row.&text=Make%20sure%20that%20the%20new,each%20font%20file%20you%20imported.)

Edit :
I agree with Hieu Dinh, you should have separate Bold, Heavy, Medium, Light and Regular .ttf files, if you add them in the .plist it should work .

Comment: Of course, i have added my font in Info.plist “Fonts provided by application”. How can i get "PDFinTextCompPro-heavy/bold" from my .ttf file? Or I need another file, with bold font only?

Comment: If you have heavy/bold in your .ttf file, then `Text("Any text").font(.custom("PFDinTextCompPro-Bold", size: 10))` or `Text("Any text").font(.custom("PFDinTextCompPro-Heavy", size: 10))` should work

Comment: I agree with Hieu Dinh, you should have separate Bold, Heavy, Medium, Light and Regular .ttf files, if you add them in the .plist it should work .

Comment: I am facing same problem. I already have all fonts listed as separate inside UIAppFonts in pList but when I use them as shown in the question, it gives no effect.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 types of fonts: **static** and **variable**.

**Static** is, well, static, one file per font: `CustomStaticFont-Regular`, `CustomStaticFont-Bold` etc. **Variable** has only one file (or a second one for italic for example).

If you have **static** fonts you should add all the files to Xcode, add them all in `Info.plist` and then use directly:

```
Text("Hello, world!")
    .font(.custom("CustomStaticFont-Regular", size: 10))
```

```
Text("Hello, world!")
    .font(.custom("CustomStaticFont-Bold", size: 10))
```

But what you want can be achieved with a **variable** font. You add it to Xcode just like all fonts, add it to `Info.plist` and then you can use those convenience modifiers:

```
Text("Hello, world!")
    .font(.custom("CustomVariableFont", size: 10))
    .bold()
```

```
Text("Hello, world!")
    .font(.custom("CustomVariableFont", size: 10))
    .fontWeight(.bold)
```

Comment: You made my day a lot easier! I found the variable font, everything goes smoothly. Beautiful.